# React state not updating in useEffect addEventListener

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I have the two following React components, one is a LinkItem with a button that show/hide a DropdownMenu, and when clicking outside of it it is supposed to callback on onClickOutside and hide

```
export default function LinkItem({ url, desc }) {
  const [menuVisible, setMenuVisible] = useState(false);
  const [menuPosition, setMenuPosition] = useState({ left: 0, top: 0 });

  return (
    <>
      <a className="bru-link-link" href={url} target="_blank">
        <div className="bru-link-data">
          <div className="bru-link-linkurl">{url}</div>
          <div className="bru-link-linkdesc">{desc}</div>
        </div>
        <div className="bru-link-menu" data-dropdown-toggle="dropdown">
          <ImageButton
            onClick={(event) => {
              event.preventDefault();
              setMenuVisible(!menuVisible);
              console.log("LinkItem setMenuVisible " + menuVisible);
              setMenuPosition({
                left: event.nativeEvent.pageX,
                top: event.nativeEvent.pageY,
              });
            }}
          >
            <svg
              xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
              fill="none"
              viewBox="0 0 24 24"
              strokeWidth="3"
              stroke="currentColor"
              className="w-6 h-6"
            >
              <path
                strokeLinecap="round"
                strokeLinejoin="round"
                d="M12 6.75a.75.75 0 110-1.5.75.75 0 010 1.5zM12 12.75a.75.75 0 110-1.5.75.75 0 010 1.5zM12 18.75a.75.75 0 110-1.5.75.75 0 010 1.5z"
              />
            </svg>
          </ImageButton>
        </div>
      </a>

      <DropdownMenu
        menuVisible={menuVisible}
        posTop={menuPosition.top}
        posLeft={menuPosition.left}
        onClickOutside={() => {
          console.log("LinkItem handleMenuClose");
          setMenuVisible(false);
        }}
      />
    </>
  );
}
```

and this is DropdownMenu that is supposed to show/hide

```
export default function DropdownMenu({
  menuVisible,
  posLeft,
  posTop,
  onClickOutside,
}) {
  const wrapperRef = useRef(null);

  const handleClickOutside = (event) => {
    //console.log(event.target);
    //console.log(wrapperRef.current);
    console.log("DropdownMenu menuVisible1: "+menuVisible);
    if (wrapperRef.current && !wrapperRef.current.contains(event.target)) {
        console.log("DropdownMenu onClickOutside");
        onClickOutside();
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    document.addEventListener("click", handleClickOutside, false);
    return () => {
      document.removeEventListener("click", handleClickOutside, false);
    };
  }, []);
  
    console.log("DropdownMenu menuVisible2: "+menuVisible);

  return (
    menuVisible && (<>
      <ul
        ref={wrapperRef}
        className={`
        absolute 
        z-[1000] 
        float-left 
        m-0  
        min-w-max 
        list-none 
        overflow-hidden 
        rounded-lg 
        border-none 
        bg-white 
        bg-clip-padding 
        text-left 
        text-base 
        shadow-lg 
        dark:bg-neutral-700 
        [&[data-te-dropdown-show]]:block
        `}
        aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton1"
        data-te-dropdown-menu-ref
        style={{
          left: posLeft + "px",
          top: posTop + "px",
          position: "absolute",
        }}
      >
        <li className="block w-full whitespace-nowrap bg-transparent py-2 px-4 text-sm font-normal text-neutral-700 hover:bg-neutral-100 active:text-neutral-800 active:no-underline disabled:pointer-events-none disabled:bg-transparent disabled:text-neutral-400 dark:text-neutral-200 dark:hover:bg-neutral-600">
          Action
        </li>
        <li className="block w-full whitespace-nowrap bg-transparent py-2 px-4 text-sm font-normal text-neutral-700 hover:bg-neutral-100 active:text-neutral-800 active:no-underline disabled:pointer-events-none disabled:bg-transparent disabled:text-neutral-400 dark:text-neutral-200 dark:hover:bg-neutral-600">
          Another action
        </li>
        <li className="block w-full whitespace-nowrap bg-transparent py-2 px-4 text-sm font-normal text-neutral-700 hover:bg-neutral-100 active:text-neutral-800 active:no-underline disabled:pointer-events-none disabled:bg-transparent disabled:text-neutral-400 dark:text-neutral-200 dark:hover:bg-neutral-600">
          Something else here
        </li>
      </ul>
    </>)
  );
}
```

How's possible that the state is correct in the `console.log("DropdownMenu menuVisible2: "+menuVisible);` (and the menu correctly show/hide) but not in the `console.log("DropdownMenu menuVisible1: "+menuVisible);` ?

I would expect it to be the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because your use effect doesn't get updated when the state is changed.
For that you need to pass the relevant states to the use effect.

```
useEffect(() => {
  document.addEventListener("click", handleClickOutside, false);
  return () => {
    document.removeEventListener("click", handleClickOutside, false);
  };
}, [menuVisible]);
```

Event tho the **handleClickOutside** function is outside the use effect, it is initiated within the use effect scope. Just to clarify the scope you could write the above code as below

```
useEffect(() => {
  document.addEventListener("click", (event) => {
    //console.log(event.target);
    //console.log(wrapperRef.current);
    console.log("DropdownMenu menuVisible1: " + menuVisible);
    if (wrapperRef.current && !wrapperRef.current.contains(event.target)) {
        console.log("DropdownMenu onClickOutside");
        onClickOutside();
    }
  }, false);

return () => {
    document.removeEventListener("click", (event) => {
        //console.log(event.target);
        //console.log(wrapperRef.current);
        console.log("DropdownMenu menuVisible1: " + menuVisible);
        if (wrapperRef.current && !wrapperRef.current.contains(event.target)) {
            console.log("DropdownMenu onClickOutside");
            onClickOutside();
        }
    }, false);
} }, [menuVisible]);
```

Hope this helps!